# Is Mac OS X's Compress a "standard" zip?

Tags: zip, compression

When I submit my research papers to an online review system, I prefer to upload all files (manuscript, figures, etc) by a single zip file, so that the review system can unzip the file. Otherwise, I have to upload many files one by one; time-consuming.

However, if I create a zip file using the Mac OS X's native Compress functionality, the review system tells it may be a corrupt file. Every time I try, it does same.

Instead if I use `zip` command in Terminal to create a zip file, it is fine.

What kind of zip technology does Compress use? Anything non-standard? Do you see any potential reasons for the fails?

Comment: Another difference is: the Mac compressed zip contains some .DS_Store files and possibly other files invisible on the Mac but not invisible in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

As its `man` page states,

> The compress utility reduces the size of files using adaptive Lempel-Ziv coding.

In contrast, the `zip` command (also present in Mac OS X, at least in Mountain Lion) uses a different algorithm. If a publisher is expecting a `zip`-compressed file, a file compressed with `compress` is something different, and will not work for this.